# for loop iteration - how to avoid comma

Tags: java

I want to get the string from two to six along with ",". When i execute the below code, i get the output but it starts with a comma..how to avoid this..?

```
    String name="";
    String s = "1,two,three,four,five,six,seven"; //this is a sample string, original string might contain more words separated by ","
    String[] split = s.split(",");
    System.out.println("Splitted Length: " +split.length);
    if(split.length>2) {
        for(int i=1; i<split.length-1;i++) {
            name = name+","+split[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println(name);
```

Output:

```
  Splitted Length: 7
 ,two,three,four,five,six
```

How to avoid that first comma..

Comment: check it before empty or not

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please stop with those for loops. Don't invent everything new. Know the API.

```
List<String> valuesList = Arrays.asList(array).subList(x, y);
String newValuesString = String.join(",", valuesList);
```

Comment: You could also use `Arrays.copyOfRange(array, x, y)` instead of creating an intermediate list

Comment: For an array this small it's probably not relevant, but I think it's faster this way since `subList` crate's only a view on a part of the List and `copyOfRange` really copies the elements.

Comment: Well you're in fact creating 3 different objects when using the list way. Because `asList` returns a wrapper class, `subList` returns a view and `join` aquires an iterator internally, so I would assume that a simple `copyOfRange` might suffice

Answer (score 3):

You can use Java8 `Stream` and `Pattern` for that.

```
String result = Pattern.compile(",").splitAsStream(s)
    .skip(1)
    .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

Comment: Just thank you. Even if you don't want to use Stream you could join the strings by simply using `String.join`

Answer (score 2):

You can rewrite your code on such way:

```
 if(split.length>2) {
        name = split[1];
        for(int i=2; i<split.length-1;i++) {
            name = name+","+split[i];
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the first element outside of the loop:

```
if(split.length>2) {
    name = split[0];
    for(int i=1; i<split.length-1;i++) {
        name = name+","+split[i];
    }
}
```

this also includes the first element (`"1"`), which you decided to omit in the result for some reason

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one,

```
  String name = "";
        String s = "1,two,three,four,five,six,seven"; 
        String[] split = s.split(",");
        System.out.println("Splitted Length: " + split.length);
        if (split.length > 2) {
            for (int i = 1; i < split.length - 1; i++) {
                if (name.isEmpty()) {
                    name = split[i];
                } else {
                    name = name + "," + split[i];
                }

            }
        }
        System.out.println(name);
    }
```

Comment: that condition is only ``true`` during the first loop iteration. Why not modify the loop?

Answer (score 0):

Try out the below code

```
String name="";
String s = "1,two,three,four,five,six,seven"; //this is a sample string, original string might contain more words separated by ","
String[] split = s.split(",");
System.out.println("Splitted Length: " +split.length);
if(split.length>2) {
    for(int i=1; i<split.length-1;i++) {
      if (i=1)            
        {name = name+split[i];}
      else 
        {name=name+","+split[i];}
    }
}
System.out.println(name);
```

EXPLANATION:- In this code the for loop uses a different(name = name+split[i];) equation just for the first interation of the for loop which helps avoid the first ","

Comment: Please format your code correctly, and provide some explanation : why the OP code is not correct and why yours is

Answer (score 0):

Store the delimiter in a variable, and update it after the first iteration:

```
String delim = "";
for(int i=1; i<split.length-1;i++) {
    name = name+delim+split[i];
    delim = ",";
}
```

However, it would just be easier to use `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf` to find the first and last commas in the string directly:

```
int first = s.indexOf(',');
int last = s.lastIndexOf(',');
if (first != last) {
    name = s.substring(first + 1, last);
}
```